# Prometheus Operator Expose Ingress Route

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I want to reach Prometheus Operator over Internet via HTTPS.

I deployed Prometheus via HELM and provided the following custom-vault.yml

**Chart Version:**

```
 kube-prometheus-0.0.105
 nginx-ingress-0.31.0
```

**Deployment:**

```
helm install coreos/kube-prometheus --name kube-prometheus --set global.rbacEnable=false \
--namespace monitoring -f custom-vault.yml
```

**What i expect**:
I want to browse Prometheus via URL
https://example.com/prometheus

**my custom-vault.yml**

```
prometheus:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    tls: 
      - secretName: tls-secret
        hosts: 
          - example.com
    hosts:
      - example.com
    paths:
      - /
  #prometheusSpec:
    #externalUrl: https://example.com/prometheus
```

**What happen?**

I can reach https://example.com/graph but CSS Files doesn´t get loaded due to path error.

When i try to configure https://example.com/prometheus/graph also CSS doesn´t work and when i click on the Frontend on Alerts then i get redireted to https://example.com/alerts and getting and "default backend 404" error.

Other Ingress Routes for serval Services / Pods are working
Prometheus is also working - when i expose the Port to localhost, Prometheus get displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your Input. You helped me to solve the problem. Not on the direct way, but it gave me a new point of view.

**How i solved the issue:**
I changed the deployment from coreos/kube-prometheus to stable/prometheus-operator

The current version is 6.11
I was not able to install directly 6.11 - i need to install 6.0.0 and upgraded to 6.11

Also provided a new custom-value.yaml

With this setting it works perfectly!

custom-value.yaml

```
prometheus:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "{my_whitelisted_public_ip}"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    tls: 
      - secretName: tls-secret
        hosts: 
          - example.com
    hosts:
      - example.com
    paths:
      - /
  prometheusSpec:
    externalUrl: http://example.com/prometheus
    routePrefix : prometheus/
```

Thank you.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Your url is : "https://example.com/prometheus" and your path is "/"

This explains why you may have some working link and not other (CSS, index...).

If I'm not wrong you should create your path like this:

```
paths:
  - /prometheus/*
```

This says, combined with your rewrite target to use /prometheus as it's root url and to accept all sub-url. The rewrite will redirect, inside the pod, to /.

Answer (score 0):

Change section

```
paths:
  - /
```

to

```
  paths:
  - prometheus:
    path: /prometheus
```

But you should remember that exposing the Prometheus web UI through an Ingress object requires a running [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

More information you can find here: [operator-prometheus-coreos](https://coreos.com/operators/prometheus/docs/latest/user-guides/exposing-prometheus-and-alertmanager.html).